# ruamel.yaml yaml_set_comment_before_after_key insert after params not work

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I have tried to insert one line comment after one key, but not worked, if insert before one key, the code can work.

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap

temp = CommentedMap()
temp["id"] = "a"
temp["name"] = "b"
# temp.yaml_set_comment_before_after_key('name', after="name: comment2", after_indent=2)
temp.yaml_set_comment_before_after_key('name', before="name: comment1", indent=2, after="name: comment2", after_indent=2)
temp["range"] = "c"
temp_list = [temp]
result = dict()
result["test"] = temp_list

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump(result, sys.stdout)
```

result is

```
test:
- id: a
  # name: comment1
  name: b
  range: c
```

The expect result is

```
test:
- id: a
  # name: comment1
  name: b
  # name: comment2
  range: c
```

I am not sure if I can only use "before" param, and key set to "range",

```
temp.yaml_set_comment_before_after_key('range', before="name: comment2")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why the `after` parameter is not used, it should give an EOL comment although of course an `indent=2` is seldom what you want.

Your expectated output should be:

```
test:
- id: a
  # name: comment1
  name: b # name: comment2
  range: c
```

It is going to be easier to only use the `before` parameter on both `name` and `range`, as that way you don't have to provide a comment with a newline (with appropriate number of spaces).